# Submenu disappear on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, submenu

My submenu disappears when i move the mouse out of a-element.
I'm a student and new to web development, so i thought i would ask here after googling for hours..

I've tried using .topbar #menus li:hover + .sub, but then the submenu wouldnt show up at all.

Appreciate all answers.

```css
.topbar #menus{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.topbar #menus > li{
    border: 2px solid rgb(20, 20, 20);
    
}

.topbar #menus li a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sub a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.sub{
    display: none;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.topbar #menus li a:hover + .sub{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Element</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topbar">
        <ul id="menus">
            <li id="food"><a href="food.html">FOOD</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li id="breakfast"><a href="#">BREAKFAST</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="drinks"><a href="drinks.html">DRINKS</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li id="colddrinks"><a href="#">COLD DRINKS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="offers"><a href="offers.html">OFFERS</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li id="foodoffers"><a href="#">FOOD OFFERS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there!

```
  .topbar #menus li:hover .sub{
    display: block;
}
```

i changed the line like this! good luck!

Comment: I thought i had tried this seven times before, but apparently not without doing other changes. bit it worked, thank you so much! :D